# How to Import compiled libs (pyd) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bpy

I could not get a working example of importing a compiled library (pyd file) in Python.

I compiled the blender source code, result is a bpy.pyd file.
This file is placed in the python\lib folder.

In the source code I have 
import bpy

The file is found at runtime, but I get a runtime error that the module could not be imported

Does someone have a good documentation on importing compiled python modules? 
I searched ~100 entries, but only general definitions on how to do this. I trued all suggestions without success.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it was found but couldn't be imported? where is the code and error traceback showing this?

Comment: Found the error - Python mismatch in the cmake files for blender that I had to use. (the pyd was compiled with 32 bit Python, but my environment is 64 bit)

But now I get the error at the line:
import bpy

Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:
the pyd file was compiled with a 32 bit Python, was called with a 64 bit Python